# Mule- How to install modfied connector

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

How to install the magneto connector with my modification from [gitHub](https://github.com/mulesoft/magento-connector) into Mule- Anypoint Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use Maven to build the connector: `mvn package -Ddevkit.studio.package.skip=false`

Then in Studio:

1. Click Help → Install New Software on the Mule menu bar.
2. Navigate to the target folder within the project directory and
       follow the instructions to install the add on.

Comment: I am getting this error: "Could not find file:/home/user/connector-0.0.1/target/", whats wrong?

Comment: You have to select the update site zip file in the target directory.